# How to conditionally hide parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a jenkins pipeline job with parameters.  I want the  parameters to show up conditionally.  The condition depends on a selection of a previous parameter.

I have tried the Active choices plug-in. It allows me to choose a value of a parameter conditionally.  I want the whole parameter to appear in the UI conditionally.

Is it possible with jenkins pipeline files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible. In the case of declarative/scripted pipelines, parameters are 'post-processed' meaning essentially the ones you see are what was evaluated in the previous 'run/build'. Which is why it takes a build before 'Build with Parameters' becomes available.

As an alternative, (if you're using scripted/declarative pipelines) you could use an Input step and make it trigger conditionally.

```
if ( x == true ) {
    def userInput = input(
       id: 'userInput', message: 'Let\'s promote?', parameters: [
       [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'uat', description: 'Environment', name: 'env'],
       [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'uat1', description: 'Target', name: 'target']
    ])
}
```

Example pulled from:
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204986450-Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs

Comment: can it helps me with this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248264/does-active-choice-reactive-parameter-support-hide-fields-option

Comment: @arielma I don't believe what you want is possible, Jenkins parameters are post processed. Which means your essentially seeing the parameters as evaluated from the LAST build. Without the build actually running there is no execution process in order to evaluate anything.

Comment: Does jenkins  blue ocean has any option dynamically hide parameters

Comment: i dont know sorry

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it appear in the Jenkins UI parameters conditionally

I needed 1 plugins, active choice parameters, also can use scriptler if want to have more powerful conditional

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin

In Jenkins configuration, you should select (Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter)
[image: Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter]

In the following image you can see the whole configuration
[image]

Name = name of the parameter.

Groovy script = script in groovy language which you can use to hide or not parameters depending in any previous parameter, in the example image you can see that my conditional depending in a parameter called 'teamType'.
the way I'm hiding or showing parameters is using HTML code, and to allow Jenkins render that HTML code you need to select at the very bottom in 'Choice Type' -> 'Formatted HTML'.

Last but not least, don't forget to add in the 'Referenced parameters' any parameter(s) you want to use for the conditional